# redirect https to http from google search

Tags: wordpress, .htaccess, ssl

Hi I remove my ssl cert from my website. I fixed the database from showing HTTPS and remove the necessary lines from htaccess file . but for now - anyone how trying to enter to my wordpress website get an error message (because the ssl...) How can I forward the user from HTTPS TO HTTP?

htaccess below:

```
text/x-generic .htaccess ( ASCII text )

# BEGIN WordPress
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /
RewriteRule ^index\.php$ - [L]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule . /index.php [L]
</IfModule>

# END WordPress

# <IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
# RewriteEngine On
# RewriteCond %{SERVER_PORT} 80 
# RewriteRule ^(.*)$ https://www.*****.com/$1 [R,L]
# </IfModule>


<IfModule mod_headers.c>    
Header add Access-Control-Allow-Origin "*" 
</IfModule>

Header unset Pragma
FileETag None
Header unset ETag

## EXPIRES CACHING ##
<IfModule mod_expires.c>
ExpiresActive On
ExpiresByType image/jpg "access 1 year"
ExpiresByType image/jpeg "access 1 year"
ExpiresByType image/gif "access 1 year"
ExpiresByType image/png "access 1 year"
ExpiresByType text/css "access 1 month"
ExpiresByType text/html "access 1 month"
ExpiresByType application/pdf "access 1 month"
ExpiresByType text/x-javascript "access 1 month"
ExpiresByType application/x-shockwave-flash "access 1 month"
ExpiresByType image/x-icon "access 1 year"
ExpiresDefault "access 1 month"
</IfModule>
## EXPIRES CACHING ##


<FilesMatch "\\.(js|css|html|htm|php|xml)$">
SetOutputFilter DEFLATE
</FilesMatch>

<IfModule mod_gzip.c>
mod_gzip_on Yes
mod_gzip_dechunk Yes
mod_gzip_item_include file \.(html?|txt|css|js|php|pl)$
mod_gzip_item_include handler ^cgi-script$
mod_gzip_item_include mime ^text/.*
mod_gzip_item_include mime ^application/x-javascript.*
mod_gzip_item_exclude mime ^image/.*
mod_gzip_item_exclude rspheader ^Content-Encoding:.*gzip.*
</IfModule>
```

Answer (score 0):

If you visit your site on http does it work? Is it just the results from Google that are still showing as SSL?

I'm sure you have but can you confirm you've def changed:

Settings > General Settings > WordPress Address (URL)

Settings > General Settings > Site Address (URL)

Comment: The website working fine from http. The problem is when I am trying to enter the website through Google, when there, there is an ssl connection.

Comment: i checked my wordpress, the adress is HTTP.

Answer (score 0):

If you're looking to simply force all `HTTPS` connections to `HTTP` then you can use the following in your `.htaccess`

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{HTTPS} on
RewriteRule ^ http://%{HTTP_HOST}%{REQUEST_URI} [L,R=301]
```

Basically, this is saying, if your website opens and `https` is ON, then it will turn it to `http`.

Comment: but HTTPS is disabled in my website, i have an expired cert

Comment: What is the actual error message that you're getting?

Comment: my website sync with cloudflare. the messege I recive is a cached Ver of the website from cloudflare services.